# how do you visually represent csv from github(My repository) in python?

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, github, google-colaboratory

I have been working for the past two hours in google colab trying to get my code to be able to visually represent the data. issue is when I read the files in, they are not csv's and I am not too sure how to cast them back to a csv. However nothing I try is working to actually get the data to be represented visually. the other major issue is that the python thinks all of the objects are Objects, so it will not let me cast them to a float or int. please help.

```html
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
headers = ['Order ID', 'Product', 'Quantity Ordered', 'Price Each', 'Order Date', 'Purchase Address']
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cshort2112/Sample-data/main/Sales_January_2019.csv'
January = pd.read_csv(url, names=headers)
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cshort2112/Sample-data/main/Sales_February_2019.csv'
February = pd.read_csv(url, names=headers)
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cshort2112/Sample-data/main/Sales_March_2019.csv'
March = pd.read_csv(url, names=headers)
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cshort2112/Sample-data/main/Sales_April_2019.csv'
April = pd.read_csv(url, names=headers)
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cshort2112/Sample-data/main/Sales_May_2019.csv'
May = pd.read_csv(url, names=headers)
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cshort2112/Sample-data/main/Sales_June_2019.csv'
June = pd.read_csv(url, names=headers)
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cshort2112/Sample-data/main/Sales_July_2019.csv'
July = pd.read_csv(url, names=headers)
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cshort2112/Sample-data/main/Sales_August_2019.csv'
August = pd.read_csv(url, names=headers)
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cshort2112/Sample-data/main/Sales_September_2019.csv'
September = pd.read_csv(url, names=headers)
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cshort2112/Sample-data/main/Sales_October_2019.csv'
October = pd.read_csv(url, names=headers)
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cshort2112/Sample-data/main/Sales_November_2019.csv'
November = pd.read_csv(url, names=headers)
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cshort2112/Sample-data/main/Sales_December_2019.csv'
December = pd.read_csv(url)

January.head()
January.dtypes

January['Price Each'] = January['Price Each'].astype(float)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out guys:

```html
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
headers = ['Order ID', 'Product', 'Quantity Ordered', 'Price Each', 'Order Date', 'Purchase Address']
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cshort2112/Sample-data/main/Sales_January_2019.csv'
January = pd.read_csv(url, names=headers)
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cshort2112/Sample-data/main/Sales_February_2019.csv'
February = pd.read_csv(url, names=headers)
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cshort2112/Sample-data/main/Sales_March_2019.csv'
March = pd.read_csv(url, names=headers)
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cshort2112/Sample-data/main/Sales_April_2019.csv'
April = pd.read_csv(url, names=headers)
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cshort2112/Sample-data/main/Sales_May_2019.csv'
May = pd.read_csv(url, names=headers)
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cshort2112/Sample-data/main/Sales_June_2019.csv'
June = pd.read_csv(url, names=headers)
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cshort2112/Sample-data/main/Sales_July_2019.csv'
July = pd.read_csv(url, names=headers)
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cshort2112/Sample-data/main/Sales_August_2019.csv'
August = pd.read_csv(url, names=headers)
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cshort2112/Sample-data/main/Sales_September_2019.csv'
September = pd.read_csv(url, names=headers)
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cshort2112/Sample-data/main/Sales_October_2019.csv'
October = pd.read_csv(url, names=headers)
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cshort2112/Sample-data/main/Sales_November_2019.csv'
November = pd.read_csv(url, names=headers)
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cshort2112/Sample-data/main/Sales_December_2019.csv'
December = pd.read_csv(url)

January.columns
January = January.to_csv('January.csv')
January

x = []
y = []
  
with open('January.csv') as csvfile:
    plots = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
      
    for row in plots:
        x.append(row[1])
        y.append(row[2])
  
plt.bar(x, y, color = 'g', width = 0.72, label = "test")
plt.xlabel('Product')
plt.ylabel('Quantity')
plt.title('Qty by product')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```